# Trigger if continously hover for certain time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger a method when a hover is made on a button for continous 1000 ms. Whenever hover is on other elements then `timeout` should be reset. How do I implement such thing using javascript/ jquery ?

Preferred solution would be one not requiring use of new plugin.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    var timer;

    $('.item').hover(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('do it')
        },  1000);
    }, function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
})
```

Update:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('do it', e.target)
        },  1000);
        $(this).data('myTimer', timer);
    }).on('mouseleave', '.item', function(e){
        clearTimeout($(this).data('myTimer'));
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3heJa/)

Comment: i use `'hover'` with `.live()` or `.on()` to apply to elements that match selector in future. could you please tell how to modify your solution  to use with `.on()`

Comment: `hover` is not an event, you need to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`